# Is the article a matter of 'location' and 'reference' and 'identification'?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

If I have a concept in mind (let us say the concept of what dogs usually are) then I label that conceptual thought in my head : in this case - 'dog'.

To me, the concept 'dog' means a living creature that has a snout and a tail and four legs and it barks.

I have *labelled the concept*: 'dog'.

.......

I then see an example of such a concept outside in the street.

I say, 'There is a dog in the street'.

I have *located an example of the concept*.

.......

I then say, 'The dog is barking'.

Having located an example of the concept, I can now refer back to that which I have already located.

And now I am *identifying it*.

....

Is this, fundamentally, what the article does ?

Does it 'locate' examples of thought-concepts (which already have word-labels attached to them) and then 'refer' to them in a way which 'identifies' them ?

==================================================================

I am looking at the article (and at the absence of the article) in a conceptual way and would appreciate any comments, thoughts or answers.

This is an ongoing project for me and it has a purpose.

=================================================================

EDIT (after comment) :

Some say that the article is derived (conceptually and etymologically) from the demonstrative pronoun. Which seems, to me, to make sense.

Comment: What do existing treatments of articles have to say on this?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Thank you for the edit. Appreciated.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am struggling through two volumes which deal with the concept of the article. Opinions seem to vary. Some say it is derived from the demonstrative pronoun : which seems to make sense.

Comment: @YosefBaskin do you mean it's a duplicate? In which case you should VTC as a duplicate of a specific question. Otherwise I think this question is fine, although it could do with a little editing.

Comment: Articles are mostly used idiomatically and have little reference to identification, except in an ongoing discourse. If a referential noun has been used -- or in some cases, inferred -- previously in a discourse, there is often an occasion to use _the_. On the other hand, use of _the_ with a previously unused noun in a discourse is usually a signal to the addressee that the speaker thinks the addressee is familiar with it.

Comment: What you think you're asking about is your business. What your addressee thinks you're asking about is what you have to deal with.

Comment: @JohnLawler I agree that the use of the article is a semantic matter (what is natural to the native speaker). I am trying to understand why it is natural and what it is that we are doing, conceptually, with the article in relation to the concepts we envisage and about which we communicate. Thank you for your input.

Comment: A specific determiner is used when the addresser believes the addressee knows exactly what we is being referred to. _Please pass me my/that/the book._ This may or may not involve an identifier role for more 'identificational' determiners than the definite article ('_my_ book, not any of the others'; '_that_ book [points]' ... adjectives and PPs are also often used as identifiers (' the _big red_ book _on the top shelf_').  But I'd say that with articles, most frequently the situation forces the article choice rather than the choice of article being a useful identificational tool as regards ...

Comment: identifying a referent within the actual world. However, the choice between definite and indefinite articles certainly provides help in identifying previous mentions (or not) within a narrative. So narrative-internal identification rather than actual-world-related identification. // There are many special usages of articles; 'the lion is a beast not to be trifled with' vs 'a lion is a beast not to be trifled with' are obviously paraphrases, but using the indefinite article here may actually focus the mind more on picturing a snarling lion!

Comment: Food for thought @EdwinAshworth. Your mention of 'the narrative'. One is dealing not with _unspoken_ (though name-labelled) concepts. One is dealing with a _narrative_ as it unfolds. Which I think was John Lawler's point. Many thanks. Appreciated. Look forward to a full answer, if you feel like it.

Comment: I think the correct proviso is _if you feel **up to** it_. I don't consider myself well versed enough on article usage to give a lengthy answer (CoBuild has a 120-page monograph on the articles, after all, and it doesn't mention either cases like 'He smiled at us with an unusual friendliness.' {non-count, I'd say}, or the zero vs null article distinction).

Comment: Really, beyond a certain point of familiarity, article rules just confuse people. The best thing to do is read, read, read. And listen, listen, listen, if you can -- but be aware that dialog in movies and tv is pretty clipped; most of the articles are just minor bumps in the syllable stream.